# Not able to install pThread on Windows Xampp

Tags: php, apache, pthreads, xampp

Update: Looks like I am not doing anything wrong here. When I execute a thread example, it works fine. I am not sure, then why am I getting those errors when I start Apache.

Any ideas?

---

I am trying to install pThread on Xampp (Windows 7) as follows:

1. My PHP version information: 5.4.7 VC9 x86

   [image]
2. I have downloaded `php_pthreads-0.0.45-5.4-ts-vc9-x86.zip`
3. Then I added `pthreadVC2.dll` to C:\xampp\php and `php_pthreads.dll` to C:\xampp\php\ext
4. In php.ini, I have added `extension=php_pthreads.dll`
5. Restarted Apache server and received following error:

   [image]

   [image]

Any suggestions on why this is not working?

Comment: I have this problem too. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't found any solution.

Answer (score 10):

I do not use Windows, but according to the people commenting in the manual, you must also add:

```
LoadFile "C:/xampp/php/pthreadVC2.dll"
```

to your httpd.conf (httpd-xampp.conf the manual mentions)

Comment: I think that is if I want to use pThreads in browser. I am using it from command prompt.

Comment: Why did you mention restarting Apache then ? Anyway, you might solve it by sticking pthreadVC2.dll in C:\Windows\System32, you might solve it by running the command in the directory with pthreadVC2.dll and php.exe ... the error you are recieving is pretty explicit, and nothing to do with pthreads extension, it's all down to having pthreadVC2 in the correct path ... which depends on what you are doing ...

Comment: I have already added pthreadVC2.dll to correct path(same as php.exe) and as per my update it is working as well. The only problem is I am getting that error when I start apache. I'll try to put it in System32 and see if that solves the problem. Thanks for replying

Answer (score 8):

Here is what I did and works for me:

1. Check your PHP's compiler version using phpinfo() as you have already done. Mine and your both is VC9
2. Download and install proper Pthread package that matches your compiler version. I downloaded "php_pthreads-0.0.45-5.4-ts-vc9-x86.zip" file. Make sure your OS version also mathes (32-bit or 64-bit).
3. Extract Zip file in a temp folder
4. Copy php_pthreads.dll to the 'bin\php\ext\' folder
5. Copy pthreadVC2.dll to the 'bin\php\' folder
6. Copy pthreadVC2.dll to the 'bin\apache\bin' folder
7. Copy pthreadVC2.dll to the 'C:\windows\system32' folder
8. Open php\php.ini and add "extension=php_pthreads.dll" without quotes at the end of file
9. Restart server and you won't get any error message.

Good luck

Comment: I worked for me too. Could you explain why we have to copy VC2.dll in 5,6 and 7 in three different places ?
in http://php.net/manual/en/pthreads.installation.php they say "Windows users need to take the additional step of adding pthreadVC2.dll (distributed with Windows releases) to their PATH." what path they are referring there ?

Comment: step 7 is not necessary btw , mine is working fine without it.

Answer (score 3):

copy "pthreadVC2.dll" file to "windows/system32" directory.then restart apache. It worked for me.