# PHP Fatal error: Class 'Threaded' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\

Tags: php, pthreads

I am trying to use pthreads in php using xampp. I'm using Windows. Followed the steps provided in http://php.net/manual/en/class.thread.php for installation.

This is the sample code I'm trying to compile:

```
class Task extends Threaded
{
    public $response;

    public function someWork()
    {
        $content = file_get_contents('http://google.com');
        preg_match('~<title>(.+)</title>~', $content, $matches);
        $this->response = $matches[1];
    }
}

$task = new Task;

$thread = new class($task) extends Thread {
    private $task;

    public function __construct(Threaded $task)
    {
        $this->task = $task;
    }

    public function run()
    {
        $this->task->someWork();
    }
};

$thread->start() && $thread->join();

var_dump($task->response);
//phpinfo();
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> Fatal error: Class 'Threaded' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\thread1.php on line 2.

[This is the phpinfo page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULdFu.png)

I tried out the solutions given for the same from-> [PHP pthreads: Fatal error: Class 'Thread' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22901578/php-pthreads-fatal-error-class-thread-not-found)

I tried comparing the PHP Extension Build version(VC14) and the pthread version (it was found to be same). Thread safety is also enabled. Also I tried loading the `pthread_VC2.dll` file into `httpd.conf` for Apache server.

But nothing worked. Please provide me with a solution.

Comment: You extended a wrong class `Threaded !=Thread`

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Even though I change it to Thread, I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
class Task extends Threaded
```

should be changed to

```
class Task extends Thread
```

as shown in the first example

```
class workerThread extends Thread
```

on the [PHP.net Site](http://php.net/manual/en/class.thread.php)

Comment: This is the error I'm getting now after making the changes you suggested Fatal error: Class 'Thread' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\thread1.php on line 2

Comment: You will have to recheck your installation of Thread as the above should now be correct.

Comment: STEP 1: I copied the pthreadVC2.dll into the C:\xampp\php directory                                   STEP 2: Copied the  php_pthreads.dll to the C:\xampp\php\ext directory           STEP 3:Copied the pthreadVC2.dll to the C:\xampp\apache\bin directory and to the C:\Windows\System32 directory.                                                              STEP 4:added the line 'extension=php_pthreads.dll' to the php.ini file.                          Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: Have you restarted Apache from the XAMPP control panel?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42437577/php-class-thread-not-found

Comment: https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads to check you have the right version

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18819784/not-able-to-install-pthread-on-windows-xampp Potential Fix

Comment: I think I got the issue:-                                                                                                         'Note that only PHP 7.2+ is now supported (requiring the current master branch of pthreads). This is due to safety issues with ZTS mode on PHP 7.0 and 7.1.'                                                                                                                  And I'm using PHP 7.1.7 as this is the latest available in the apache website.